# How to set active document editable when userform is opened?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a userform. If I open the userform, I am unable to edit in the active document. I need to handle both userform and active document simultaneously.

For example: If we press ctrl+f, the find dialog box will be displayed. With that dialog box open we can scroll, edit etc in the active document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite easy- all you need is to open/show UserForm in `modeless` state. You can do it by adding additional parameter to `.Show` method:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

Please keep in mind that it is for `UserForm`, not for `Message Box (MsgBox)`.

Comment: I tried it. When I click in the active document with userform opened,userform is become hidden.I want both active document and userform visible and editable. By using `vbmodeless` option I could move my cursor to active document without closing userform but as soon as I keep cursor in the active document the userform is not visible.

Comment: what I do- I resize the document/application window to 75% of screen width and move UserForm outside Word application to area of 25% left. 
To have both form as a kind of panel which could be docked and visible you need to do it in VSTO with either C# or VB.Net where you could create something like `Custom Task Pane`.

Comment: Can you give any start-up program to acheive this?From that I will make up to my requirements. Because I don't know c# nor VB.Net

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577747/excel-custom-task-pane-not-showing) and other search in google.

Comment: Modeless mode itself worked fine for me. The issue was with some other macros made userform modeless mode failure.