# Excel Task Pane Not Showing

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins, customtaskpane

I'm trying to create an Excel Add-In with a custom task pane. I've followed [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590.aspx) want to show a Windows Forms control when a user clicks a custom button on the ribbon. However, the only time I can get the pane to show is when I added a test message box on the `This_AddIn_Startup` event. Here's the relevant code:

### **ThisAddIn.cs**

```
private InputControl myInputControl { get; set; }
private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane {get;set;}


    public CustomTaskPane TaskPane
    {
        get
        {
            return myCustomTaskPane;

        }

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("loading"); //If I comment this out, task pane won't show

        myInputControl = new InputControl();
        try
        {
            myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myInputControl, "Test Task Pane");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
        myCustomTaskPane.VisibleChanged +=
    new EventHandler(myCustomTaskPane_VisibleChanged);

    }
```

### **Ribbon.cs**

```
public partial class Ribbon
{
    private void Ribbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnPullData_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.Visible = true;


    }

    private void txtPosition_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577747/excel-custom-task-pane-not-showing) and disabled all other add-ins but that still didn't work.

While debugging if I put a break point on `btnPullData_Click` and noticed there was an exception getting thrown when it was not showing. Here are the two screenshots.

### **Pane loads correctly (message box enabled)**

[image]

### **Pane doesn't load (no message box)**

[image]

Full exception text:

```
base = {System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Microsoft.Office.Core._CustomTaskPane.get_Window()
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPaneImpl.get_Window()}
```

I'm somewhat of a newbie writing C#, how do I even go about troubleshooting that exception? I don't understand how adding in a `MessageBox` temporarily fixes the problem.

Edit: Changed title

Comment: is there any more info I can provide that would be helpful? I'm sure someone has run into this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never figured out exactly why my task pane wouldn't show when creating it from scratch. However, using [VSTO Contrib](https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/VSTOContrib) I was able to use the Excel Demo project as a template and insert my own code where needed. The custom pane displays easily within Excel every time now.

Helpful video to get started [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y9YAvHi7mk)