# Excel VSTO Addin showing/hiding taskpane

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I do the tutorial here. Everything works fine with a blank excel page

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590(v=vs.120).aspx

When I load up a excel sheet someone gave me and go to click the toggleButton1 to show the pane I get

{"The taskpane has been deleted or is otherwise no longer valid."}

on the line

```
   private void toggleButton1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.Visible = ((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked;
    }
```

Is a pointer to that task pane somehow going away?

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane PartPhotoTaskPane;
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WindowActivate += Application_WindowActivate;

        void Application_WindowActivate(Excel.Workbook Wb, Excel.Window Wn)
    {
        if (PartPhotoTaskPane != null)
        {
            PartPhotoTaskPane.Dispose();
            InitalizePartPhotoViewerTaskPane(EPPF);
        }
        else
        {
            InitalizePartPhotoViewerTaskPane(EPPF);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start up the part photo viewer task pane
    /// </summary>
    private void InitalizePartPhotoViewerTaskPane(ExcelPartPhotoFunctions _EPPF)
    {
        //intialize the part search
        try
        {
            PartPhotoTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new PartPhotoSearchPane(_EPPF), "Part Information", Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow);
            PartPhotoTaskPane.Visible = Properties.Settings.Default.InfoPaneOpenStatus;
            PartPhotoTaskPane.Width = 260;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error starting Part Info Toolbar:" + Environment.NewLine +
            e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

ATTEMPT 1:

Still error on the click event. I am guessing it is something related to me needing to share that pane between classes?

```
private void toggleButton1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.Visible = ((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked;
    }


  private void ExcelEvents_WorkbookActivate(Excel.Workbook wb)
    {
        var taskPane = (customTaskPanes.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Target == wb).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).FirstOrDefault());

        if (taskPane == null)
        {
            UcCenlarInvest control = new UcCenlarInvest();
            taskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(control, "My pane for workbook " + wb.Name);
            customTaskPanes[new WeakReference(wb)] = taskPane;
        }
    }
```

ATTEMPT 2:

So now the Ribbon class can get the TaskPane yet I Still get the same error. Added this :

```
  private CustomTaskPane taskPane;
    public CustomTaskPane TaskPane
    {
        get
        {
            //return (customTaskPanes.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Target == wb).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).FirstOrDefault());
              return pane;
        }
        set
        {
            taskPane = value;
        }
    }
```

.....

```
  TaskPane = (customTaskPanes.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Target == wb).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: what version of Excel do you have ?

Comment: This is 2016. Though a person who is on 2013 uses it and has same issue. I have a awkward workaround of pasting the data into the working blank excel sheet but that is not good... any there is very little help on this topic (C# Excel Application plguins) on the internet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excel 2016 is a single document interface (SDI), each workbook in a single instance of Excel contains its own ribbon UI. [more information](https://github.com/vdeluna/VBA_Excel_Test/blob/master/en-us/content/596f5bd6-6a03-4d33-8002-f2c083f7bc79.md)

If you open a new workbook, a new ribbon appears, however the pointer to the taskpane is lost. You should implement a WorkbookActivate event and add a new task pane if no task pane already exist for it. You should also keep a static list of pointer to the custom taskpanes.

see this solution : [CustomTaskPane in Excel doesn't appear in new Workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160158/customtaskpane-in-excel-doesnt-appear-in-new-workbooks)

Comment: So in theory this error should not happen in Excel 2013?  (I will install that today to try it)

Comment: @punkouter no you will have the same problem with Excel 2013 since it is also a SDI - see the link "more information".

Comment: I think my problem is related to the line  Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.Visible = ((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked; when I refer to that TaskPane I need to refer to the code that looks for a pane and creates a new one if it does not exists.. But that is in another event

Comment: I fixed it.. I had 2 Custom panes in the code by mistake and that was confusing things

Answer (score 2):

You can also work around this by checking the taskpane control's `IsDisposed` property, for example

```
if (taskPane.CustomTaskPane?.Control.IsDisposed == false)
{
    taskPane.CustomTaskPane.Visible = false;
}
```